# Need assistance with Javascript Calculation using event.currentTarget

Tags: javascript

I keep getting Infinity as a result when I try to test this calculation script. This is my first attempt doing this without using a form element. I have tried rounding to two decimals but I fear the problem is with how I am referencing the button id. Again this is my first time using this method as opposed to a form/submit and I really need assistance figuring out what I am doing wrong. It appears that I am not getting the id of the current target properly.

```js
scene.clickHandler = function(event) {
  var button = event.currentTarget;
  var termId = event.currentTarget.id;
  var carCost = 26899;
  var myPmt = carCost / termId;
  document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = (26899 / event.currentTarget.id);
  if (this.currentButton && this.currentButton !== button) {
    this.currentButton.classList.remove('selected');
  }
  button.classList.add('selected');
};
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>AUTOMOTIVE RETAIL BASICS</h2>
  <h1>MONTHLY PAYMENT</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <img src="images/1000/1000.jpg">


  <div class="text">
    <h1>WHAT'S MY MONTHLY PAYMENT?</h1>

    <p id='cost' value='26899'>Vehicle base Price:$26,899</p>

    <p>
      <button id='36' class='text' value='36' type='submit'><label>36 MOS</label></button>
      <button id='48' class='text' type='submit' value='48'><label>48 MOS</label></button>
      <button id='60' class='text' type='submit' value='60'><label>60 MOS</label></button></p>

    <p>Monthly Payment:
      <div id='payment'></div>
    </p>

  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] by creating a new scene and add whatever else is relevant

Comment: Also why type="submit" Are you submitting anything or just calculating?

Comment: Thanks, initially I was using a form element and I forgot to remove the submit. Also, I am not sure what you mean by create a new scene and add whatever else is relevant. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: When I simply try to display the currentTarget.id I get undefined.

Comment: Element IDs cannot be numeric.

Comment: @Aioros I think they can. Not a good idea but they can

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, so what would be the best way to accomplish this? Once the user clicks the button I need to get that value for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `currentTarget` here? Why not `target`? `currentTarget` is the element you attached the listener to but `target` is what triggers it. And so `event.currentTarget.id;` will evaluate to `null` or `""` for a target which has no id. And division by `null` or `""` generates `Infinity`. 
Just use `target` instead of `currentTarget`.